# Trouble animating a button created at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a UniformGrid which containts a bunch of buttons and when the UniformGrid first displays it cycles through animating each button to appear. This all works fine but when the user pushes a certain button all the buttons are removed from the grid and some new ones are created in and again are animated.

Here is how I create the buttons in code

```
    int ModelsAnimateIndex = 0;  // Index of button to animate

    private void GetModels()
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Globals.ModelsPath);
        FileInfo[] fis = di.GetFiles();

        // ugModels is the UniformGrid

        switch (fis.Length)
        {
            case 1:
                ugModels.Rows = 1;
                ugModels.Columns = 1;
                break;
            case 2:
                ugModels.Rows = 1;
                ugModels.Columns = 2;
                break;
            case 3:
            case 4:
                ugModels.Rows = 2;
                ugModels.Columns = 2;
                break;
            case 5:
            case 6:
                ugModels.Rows = 2;
                ugModels.Columns = 3;
                break;
            case 7:
            case 8:
            case 9:
                ugModels.Rows = 3;
                ugModels.Columns = 3;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        foreach (FileInfo s in fis)
        {
            ugModels.Children.Add(new Button()
            {
                Background = ThemeColour,                             // SolidBrush
                Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White),
                Name = "btn" + s.Name.Split('.')[0].Replace(" ",""),
                Style = MainButtonStyle,                              // Button Style
                Content = s.Name.Split('.')[0]
            });
        }
    }
```

and now the button click event which starts animating the newly created buttons

```
private void btnModelSelect_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.
        sbShowMenuButton.Completed += new EventHandler(sbShowModels_Completed);
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(sbShowMenuButton.Children[0], ((Button)ugModels.Children[ModelsAnimateIndex]).Name);
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(sbShowMenuButton.Children[1], ((Button)ugModels.Children[ModelsAnimateIndex]).Name);
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(sbShowMenuButton.Children[2], ((Button)ugModels.Children[ModelsAnimateIndex]).Name);
        sbShowMenuButton.Begin((Button)ugModels.Children[ModelsAnimateIndex]); // Error is here
    }
```

When the first button tries to animate I get the following error

'btnTestModel' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.Button'.

Comment: Try using SetTarget instead of SetTargetName. You have a reference to the object anyway, so why make WPF have to look it up?

Comment: When changing to SetTarget I get the following error on Begin. '[Unknown]' property does not point to a DependencyObject in path '(0).(1)[0].(2)'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem. I needed to create the RenderTransform on the buttons created like so.

```
foreach (FileInfo s in fis)
        {
            ugModels.Children.Add(new Button()
            {
                Background = ThemeColour,
                //          This Fixed the problem           //
                RenderTransform = new TransformGroup()
                {
                    Children = new TransformCollection()
                    {
                        new ScaleTransform(),
                        new SkewTransform(),
                        new RotateTransform(),
                        new TranslateTransform()
                    }
                },                
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////
                BorderBrush = null,
                Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White),
                Name = "btn" + s.Name.Split('.')[0].Replace(" ", ""),
                Margin = new Thickness(12, 12, 12, 12),
                FontSize = 48,
                Style = MainButtonStyle,
                Content = s.Name.Split('.')[0]
            });
        }
```

thanks to Matt's sugestion, I also modified setting the storyboard

```
private void btnMenu_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sbShowMenuButton.Completed += new EventHandler(sbShowModels_Completed);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(sbShowMenuButton, ((Button)ugModels.Children[ModelsAnimateIndex]));            
        sbShowMenuButton.Begin();
    }
```